# Should a Purchase Order be capitalized as it is a noun, or can be lower case 'purchase order'?

Tags: capitalization

Hope somebody can clarify? Histroically in all the contracts I have been involved with, 'Purchase Order' has always been capitalized as I thought it is a 'thing'. I'm currently engaged with a person who continues to strike-through/red-line the spelling and writes in 'purchase order'. Are both allowed or should it/term be capitalized?

Comment: In contracts, nouns that are capitalized are defined within the contract and have a particular meaning. The same word can also be noncapitalized, and then it has it's ordinary meaning.

Comment: The word "noun" is a noun.

Comment: Unless it's the first word in a sentence or used in a title that uses title caps, only proper nouns should be capitalized. If you can use the indefinite article, it's very likely *not* a proper noun.